# How to list down all methods with livescript?

Tags: livescript

In python there is dir(module):

`In [6]: dir(datetime)
Out[6]: 
['MAXYEAR',
 'MINYEAR',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'date',
 'datetime',
 'datetime_CAPI',
 'time',
 'timedelta',
 'tzinfo']`

Elixir you can type the modulename then press tab and then it will list down all of the function that a method has.

`iex(1)> String.
Chars                 at/2                  capitalize/1

codepoints/1          contains?/2           downcase/1

duplicate/2           ends_with?/2          first/1

from_char_list!/1     from_char_list/1      graphemes/1

last/1                length/1              ljust/2

ljust/3               lstrip/1              lstrip/2

match?/2              next_codepoint/1      next_grapheme/1`

In ruby you have `methods`

`[2] pry(main)> File.methods
=> [:directory?,
 :exist?,
 :exists?,
 :readable?,
 :readable_real?,
 :world_readable?,
 :writable?,
 :writable_real?,
 :world_writable?,
 :executable?,
 :executable_real?,
 :file?,
 :zero?,
 :size?, ...]`

Is there an equivalent in livescript ?

Comment: See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a function from [prelude.ls](http://preludels.com) - `keys` - http://preludels.com/#keys

edit:

Use the `-d` flag to automatically import prelude.ls into the repl.

```
$ lsc -d
LiveScript 1.2.0 - use 'lsc --help' for more information
ls> keys require 'assert'
[ 'AssertionError',
  'fail',
  'ok',
  'equal',
  'notEqual',
  'deepEqual',
  'notDeepEqual',
  'strictEqual',
  'notStrictEqual',
  'throws',
  'doesNotThrow',
  'ifError' ]
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good way of doing it. I found that I could also press the tab key for modules that are loaded by default or "builtins" for livescript to tell me all of their modules.